# Microsoft Dependency Injection Library

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

A would like to make my ASP.NET Core project could see only another library: Api, where I have interfaces. And another library makes wiring for interfaces and their implementation.

Instead of it Microsoft Dependency Injection Library proposes to make a wiring point right in the asp.net project. In this case this project will see both libraries: Api and ApiImpl. And it's not acceptable.

I wanna find a solution like Ninject, for example, does with modules.

Comment: the English is hard to understand.

Comment: A想让我的ASP.NET Core项目只能看到另一个库：Api，我有接口。 另一个库为接口及其实现进行布线。
而不是微软的依赖注入库建议在asp.net项目中正确的接线点。 在这种情况下，这个项目将看到两个库：Api和ApiImpl。 这是不可接受的。
我想找一个解决方案像Ninject，例如，与模块。

Comment: The google translated one is even harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A kind solution of this is here:

https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/497